# Increment X in String

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make an Application which forms this string:

> 1.2.3.X

Into this strings:

> 1.2.3.0
>
> 1.2.3.1
>
> 1.2.3.2
>
> 1.2.3.3
>
> 1.2.3.4
>
> ......

And so on
I made this code:

```js
String.prototype.count=function(c) { 
  var result = 0, i = 0;
  for(i;i<this.length;i++)if(this[i]==c)result++;
  return result;
};
var x = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]
var brutenumber = ""
var ip = "1.2.X.X"
if (ip.count(".") >= 4) {
 console.log("Non valid IP Input"); 
} 
else { 
  numberX = ip.count("X");
  if (numberX < 1) {
   console.log("No X given.") 
  }
  else if (numberX > 12)  {
    console.log("Too many X given! Result can't be an IP")
  } 
  else {
    for (i = 1;i <= numberX ; i++ ) {
      brutenumber = brutenumber + "9";
      
    }
  }
  
for (d = 0;d <= brutenumber; d++) {
  var lastchar = d.toString().slice(-1);
  console.log(lastchar)
/*var wee = d.toString().substring(0,1);
console.log(wee)*/

}
}
```

My App already calculates how many tries you need to get all possibilities,
but now I ran into a problem:
My Code should generate Numbers like 001, in the for loop

```
for (d = 0 ;d <= brutenumber; d++) {
```

The problem is: It generates Numbers like 0,1...10,11,12
So I would have to set string d like brutenumber, get the length of brutenumber and then make a for loop, i <= brutenumber.length  which adds a 0 to the string d all the time.
Now the biggest problem: I have to set in the Values for the X in the searchString 1.2.3.X 
I dont have any idea how to do that.
(SearchString doesnt have to be 1.2.3.X, it can also be 1.2.X.X, 127.0.X.X, or even XXX.XXX.XXX :D )

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as far as i have understood you might come up with a solution like this;

```js
function ipListGenerator(s){
  var nos = Array(256).fill().map((_,i) => "0".repeat(2 - ~~Math.log10(i))+i);
  return nos.map(no => s.replace(/x/i,no));
}

var ipList = ipListGenerator("1.2.3.X");
console.log(ipList)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or you might simplify the code further by merging the two `.map()`s in one  as follows;

```
function ipListGenerator(s){
  return Array(256).fill().map((_,i) => s.replace(/x/i, "0".repeat(2 - ~~Math.log10(i))+i));
}
```

As per your comment.. It simplifies the code significantly as follows.

```js
function ipListGenerator(s){
  return Array(10).fill().map((_,i) => s.replace(/x/i, i));
}

console.log(ipListGenerator("1.2.3.x"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Stretching the above code a little further, you may have multiple `x` values to be filled among 0-9. However as mentioned in one of my comment this is a combinatorics job and it might get pretty time consuming depending on the number of `x`s. Especially since the above code does string operations over regex, it might turn out to be even worse. I wouldn't advise you to apply this code to a string with more than 5 `x`s.

```js
function fillxs(s){
  function runner(s){
    return Array(10).fill().map((_,i) => s.replace(/x/i, i));
  }
  var xc = s.match(/x/ig).length;
  result = [s];
  while (xc--) result = result.reduce((r,s) => r.concat(runner(s)),[])
  return result;
}

var nox = [];
console.time("test");
nox = fillxs("1.1.1x3.x1x");
console.timeEnd("test");
console.log(nox);
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer!

Comment: But I have a problem: When I put in 1.2.3.X, it prints out 1.2.3.000,1.2.3.001.. until 255, but it should be 1.2.3.0, 1.2.3.1,1.2.3.2 to 9 :)

Comment: @GeT_rApEd So let me get it right.. when you enter "1.2.3.X" you expect an array of only 10 strings like ["1.2.3.0","1.2.3.1","1.2.3.2",...,"1.2.3.8","1.2.3.9"] right.. So i have added a code below my answer.

Comment: Hm, It shouldnt always just put in 10 times, imagine it like this:

Comment: You want to crack a password, you have a few values given, and a few not these are X, you want to try everything. So not only when I say the function to get all the strings of 1.2.3.X, it should also  work with 127.0.X.X or 1XX.2X1.67X, or even XXX.XXX.XXX it can be everything. Sorry for being so complicated

Comment: And if I put in 1.2.X.X the first output should be 1.2.0.1 not 1.2.3.X.1

Comment: and btw im not cracking a password, just making a scanner for a game

Comment: @GeT_rApEd OK i got it. What you want is about combinatorics. However you can still do this task with the above code. Assume that you give `"1.2.x.x"` to the function and you will get a results array like `["1.2.0.x","1.2.1.x","1.2.3.x",...,"1.2.8.x","1.2.9.x"]` in return. Now you have to repeat the same operation per array item by utilizing a `map.()` and concatenate the results. Can you implement this? If not, then i can do this later tonight once i have some free time.

Comment: little push :))

Comment: @GeT_rApEd Hi, sorry for late return. I have modified the code to handle multiple `x`s however as i also mention in the extended part of my answer, do not apply it to a string with more than 5 `x`s or you will GeT_bOrEd.

Comment: I have one more question: I want to count up 111111111 to 999999999, how can I do that without javascript crashing? Tried making sleeps between it, crashed anyways